# What is an example of a space that is contractible but not homeomorphic to a convex set?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

As the title says, are there any examples of a contractible space which is not homeomorphic (or maybe homotopy equivalent) to a convex space?

Comment: The space $\mathbf X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convex sets have the following property: they are contractible to all of their points, i.e. you can find a contraction collapsing the set to any given point you choose. This property is easily seen to be preserved by homeomorphism. So an example will be any space that is contractible, but not to all of its points; a classical example is the Topologist's comb: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space.

[image]

Comment: Let $X$ be contractible. For every map $\{\ast\} \to X$, the map $X \to \{\ast\}$ is a homotopy inverse. That is, you can take any point of $X$ as the center of contraction.